# Laravel 5 - Install TwitterOAuth library by Abraham

Tags: laravel, twitter-oauth

I am trying to install abraham's twitteroauth library (https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) in laravel 5  using composer. Added the project in composer.json like this

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "abraham/twitteroauth": "0.5.2"
},
```

when i run composer update I receive an error at the end

```
- Installing abraham/twitteroauth (0.5.2)
  Loading from cache

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::getCachedCompilePath()

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error

[RuntimeException]
Error Output:

update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

any help is Welcome

Comment: Hi Amit, not related but have you considered Laravel 5's native socialite module? https://github.com/laravel/socialite this provides twitter oAuth authentication as part of the Laravel 5 Auth implementation.

Comment: thanks @DavidBarker will try the socialite module

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem with the library you are installing.

When Laravel v5.0.16 was released the compiled script location was changed and an [upgrade guide was released](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade#upgrade-5.0.16). The unfortunate problem is that by running a composer update you would have upgraded to 5.0.16 without knowing any of this, as such you need to open `bootstrap/autoload.php` and change the `$compiledPath` variable.

```
// Change the current variable to this instead
$compiledPath = __DIR__.'/../vendor/compiled.php';
```

This will get it working again for you.

Comment: Didn't notice this before. But receiving the same error just running composer update inside a fresh installation. So, "composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel5"   and then, after installation "composer update"   same error. Compiled path is as you specified.

Comment: deleting the vendor direectory and running composer update after that fixed the issue. thanks for help

Comment: Running composer dump-auto load would have fixed that problem, sorry didn't see this any sooner.